# Set sprint board for Test & Feedback extension

Tags: testing, azure-devops

How do you set the sprint board which bugs & tasks are assigned to with the Test & Feedback extension?

We've installed and connected the Test & Feedback extension for Chrome on our Product Owner's laptop so that he can log bugs; but whenever he creates a bug or task it is always assigned to the sprint we were in when we set him up, not the current sprint. How does he ensure that his bug is assigned to the current sprint or, preferably, the backlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs/tasks created by Test & Feedback extension usually set for current sprint.
But there is one situation that will caused the bugs/tasks are not set for current sprint: **session for Test & Feedback extension never stopped even the current sprint become past sprint with days going on**.

For example, a session for Test & Feedback extension is started at Aug 20th, and the **Sprint1** was started from Aug 19th to Aug 26th. So during Aug 20th to Aug 26th, bugs created on the extension were set to Sprint1. When the day of Aug 27th came, your current sprint is **Sprint2** (assume from Aug 27 to Sep 4th) now. But if the session on the extension were not stopped and started again after Aug 26th, the session always trace the Sprint1.

So please stop the session and start again when the current sprint is changed.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much!